# Find/replace multiple lines in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have hundreds of xml files that have different types of IDs e.g. submitter, requester, agent etc. I want to do a find/replace just the value for the **Requester ID**. XML is displayed thus:

```
<Submitter>
    <ID>1578642S</ID>
</Submitter>

<Requester>
    <ID>1748791R</ID>
</Requester>

<Agent>
    <ID>198791A</ID>
</Agent>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find:

```
<Requester>\s*<ID>\w+</ID>\s*</Requester>
```

Replace:

```
<Requester>\n<ID>newID</ID>\n</Requester>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I expanded what you had a bit further to retain format in the XML: <Requester>\n\t\t<ID>newID</ID>\n\t</Requester>

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a task for xpath, not for regex or find-replace. 
Since you are navigating an xml to find a particular tag and replace it's text value, not finding a text pattern. an xpath code like

```
'//Requester/ID/*'
```

should get you all instances of Requester/ID in your XML... 
you'll just need to wrap it in a script (of your prefered language) to iterate over the documents and replace the values and you'll be done in no time.